Vue, Java Servlet: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check cors error while trying to send post request
I'm trying to send a post request from Vue frontend to my Java Servlet bankend, but I still got an error like Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/cache/cacheInfo?cacheType=22' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
Please help me check with my backend cors filter:enter image description hereenter image description here
